# How to define a partial function in Isabelle?

Tags: isabelle

I tried to define a partial function with the `partial_function` keyword. It did not work. Here is the one that expresses the intuition best:

```
partial_function (tailrec) oddity :: "nat => nat"
where
  "oddity Zero = Zero "
| "oddity (Succ (Succ n)) = n"
```

and then I tried the following:

```
partial_function (tailrec) oddity :: "nat => nat"
where
  "oddity arg = ( case arg of (Succ (Succ n)) => n
                          | Zero => Zero
                )"

partial_function (tailrec) oddity :: "nat => nat"
where
  "oddity (Succ(Succ n)) = n
   | oddity Zero = Zero"

partial_function (tailrec) oddity :: "nat => nat"
where
  "oddity n =
   (if n = Zero then Zero
    else if (n >= 2)
      then do { m ← oddity (n-2); m })"
```

None of them worked. I guess my attempts have conceptual and syntactic problems, what are these?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two problems with your definitions:

1. `partial_function` does not support pattern-matching on the left hand side. This must be emulated with `case` expressions on the right.
2. The constructors for type `nat` are `Suc` and `0`, not `Succ` and `Zero`. This is why your case expressions generate the error that `Succ` and `Zero` are not datatype constructors, and why `parital_function` complains that `Zero` is an extra variable on the right hand side.

In summary, the following works:

```
partial_function (tailrec) oddity :: "nat => nat"
where "oddity arg = (case arg of (Suc (Suc n)) => n | 0 => 0 )"
```

You can recover simplification rules with pattern-matching by using the `simp_of_case` conversion from `~~/src/HOL/Library/Simps_Case_Conv`:

```
simps_of_case oddity_simps[simp]: oddity.simps

thm oddity_simps
```

Comment: What does the `thm` command do there? The Isar reference manual says that it "retrieves" the theorem but I guess there is some side-effect lurking here.

Comment: `thm` is used to see the actual statement of a fact. That is, the side-effect (and actually only effect) is that the fact corresponding to the given name(s) is shown (the location depends on the user-interface).

Answer (score 2):

Some comments concerning your last example:

1. There is no `if-then` without `else` in Isabelle/HOL. Thus a syntax error. To fix this you would have to either provide an `else`-branch for your last `if`, or rewrite the definition. E.g.

   ```
    partial_function (tailrec) oddity :: "nat ⇒ nat"
    where
      "oddity n = (
        if n = 0 then 0
        else if n ≥ 2 then do { m ← oddity (n - 2); m }
        else undefined)"
   ```
2. At this point there will be an error about "unresolved adhoc overloading". Remember that do-notation is just syntactic sugar. Lets try to see what is actually happening by just looking at the do-block with

   ```
    term "do { m ← oddity (n - 2); m }"
   ```

Since there is still the unresolved overloading lets fix the type of `m` to `'a list` and also deactivate "pretty printing" for adhoc overloading as follows

```
    declare [[show_variants]]
    term "do { m ← oddity (n - 2); (m :: 'a list) }"
```

The result is

```
    "List.bind (oddity (n - 2)) (λm. m)"
```

So you see that instead of the semicolon `;` you typed, a constant `bind` is inserted (the exact constant depends on the type). There is no `bind` registered for type `nat`, hence the above error. While you could define some kind of "identity monad" this rather shows that do-notation does not make much sense here. How about the following definition instead?

```
    partial_function (tailrec) oddity :: "nat ⇒ nat"
    where
      "oddity n = (
        if n = 0 then 0
        else if n ≥ 2 then oddity (n - 2)
        else undefined)"
```

**Update:**

3. It might not be your intention that `oddity 1` is undefined. But since I'm not sure about the purpose of `oddity` I can't be sure about that.

**!!!!!! As pointed out by Charles Staats in a comment below. The following does not work as expected !!!!!!**

For completeness sake, lets see how we could define the above mentioned identity monad. First we need a bind operation, i.e., a constant taking an identity monad and a function returning an identity monad and combining those arguments into an identity monad. A first, and most simple idea could be

```
    definition "bind_id' x f = f x"
```

which is just function application in reverse order. However, with this definition we will later get problems with monotonicity of `bind_id'` that will be required for `(tailrec)`. Thus we instead use

```
    definition "bind_id x f = (if x = undefined then undefined else f x)"
```

which guarantees that `bind_id x f` is `undefined` whenever `x` is, and thus is monotone. Then we register this new constant for adhoc overloading of the monadic bind like so

```
    adhoc_overloading
      Monad_Syntax.bind bind_id
```

Now it remains to prove monotonicity of `bind_id` w.r.t. `mono_tailrec`, which is left as an exercise (just mimic what is already done for `mono_option` in `Partial_Function`). Then your definition using do-notation would be accepted.

Comment: Thanks. For 3.: yes this was meant to be a minimal example of a partial function that is not defined for odd naturals, hence the name.

Comment: There's an issue with your definition of bind_id. `undefined` is an element of `nat` (or whatever type you are working with), you just can't prove anything about *which* element it is. So, for instance, you can never prove `bind_id 17 Succ = 18` because `undefined` could be 17. You could prove `bind_id 17 Succ \<in> {17, 18}`, but that's not really what `bind_id` is supposed to be doing IIUC.

Comment: @CharlesStaats Thnx for pointing that out. I explicitly marked the part of my answer that does not work.