# 'case _ of' non-datatype constant args, simps_of_case

Tags: isabelle

I was looking at the `case` operator, to see what it can do for me.

There's not a problem. Given the examples I'm working with, I accept that "it does what it does", but I ask some questions in case there's something more to learn.

1. It appears that the `case` operator can't take arguments that are constants unless they're `datatype` constants. If they aren't, it gives the uninformative message: *"Error in case expression: type mismatch"*.

   - Can I get `case` to pattern match on a non-datatype constant?
2. The keyword `simps_of_case` sometimes produces simp rules from a `case`, and sometimes it doesn't.

   - Is there something I should know about the example below where it just reproduces the `yield2_def` as the simp rule?

I took one example for `simps_of_case` from [How to define a partial function in Isabelle?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25281857). It seems that I learned somewhere that `case` is designed around `datatype`, but I don't find where I learned about that.

I include a short theory with the examples:

```
theory i150903a__a0  
imports Complex_Main "~~/src/HOL/Library/Simps_Case_Conv"
begin 
(*************************************************************************)
section{* simps_of_case: Doesn't generate any new simps *}

(*(58)/src/HOL/Lazy_Sequence.thy
[∙) Doesn't generate any new simp rules. Because of 'list_of_lazy_sequence'?*)
definition yield2 :: "'a lazy_sequence => ('a × 'a lazy_sequence) option"
where
  "yield2 xq = (case list_of_lazy_sequence xq of
    [] => None
  | x # xs => Some (x, lazy_sequence_of_list xs))"

thm yield2_def  
find_theorems name: yield2

simps_of_case yield2_simps[simp]: yield2_def

thm yield2_simps
find_theorems name: yield2

(*************************************************************************)
section{* simps_of_case: Does generate new simps *}

(*140813a__SOz__How to define a partial function in Isabelle*)
partial_function (tailrec) oddity :: "nat => nat" where 
  "oddity x = (case x of (Suc (Suc n)) => n | 0 => 0 )"

thm oddity.simps  
find_theorems name: oddity

simps_of_case oddity_simps[simp]: oddity.simps

thm oddity_simps
find_theorems name: oddity

(*************************************************************************)
section{* Case constant arguments must be datatypes? *}

declare[[show_sorts]]
(*Works*)
term "case (x,y) of (None, None) => (0::'a::zero, 0::'b::zero)"

term "case (x,y) of (0::nat, 0::nat) => (0::'a::zero, 0::'b::zero)"

term "case (x,y) of (0::nat, x # xs) => (0::'a::zero, 0::'b::zero)"

term "case (x,y) of (a,b) => (0::'a::zero, 0::'b::zero)"

fun foofun :: "('a::zero, 'b::zero) prod => ('a, 'b) prod" where
  "foofun (x,y) = (case (x,y) of (a,b) => (0,0))"

(*OUTPUT: "Error in case expression: type mismatch"*)  
term "case (x,y) of (0::nat, 0::int) => (0::'a::zero, 0::'b::zero)"

fun foofun :: "('a::zero, 'b::zero) prod => ('a, 'b) prod" where
  "foofun (x,y) = (case (x,y) of (0,0) => (0,0))"

(*************************************************************************)
section{* Theory end *}
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Case syntax is only sugar – it gets desugared to a nested application of the appropriate "case combinators". The datatype manual hints at that briefly in §2.3. As far as I know, there must be a case combinator for a given type in order for case syntax to work. Existing case combinators are e.g. `case_option` and `case_list`. Now, if something has not been defined as a datatype, there are other ways to obtain that combinator (e.g. the `free_constructors`) command. The `int` doesn't have that kind of setup.
2. `simps_of_case` transforms an equation of the form `f x = P (case x of ...)` into equations of the form `f pat1 = P ...`, `f pat2 = P ...`, ... If you're pattern matching on a term which is not a variable from the argument list, it can't do that. In your example, what did you expect to get generated?

Comment: Lars, thanks. There are 2 cases `[]` and `x # xs`, so I thought it would be nice to get more than `yield2_def`, but I was only comparing it to the other example, doing plug'n'play experiments. I was trying to see if case does things to get past limitations of pattern matching with `fun`, but I think I see now that it's like 'if/then/else', where it can be used as an operator in function defs. I didn't find an over abundance of places it's used in the HOL sources. I was looking for examples where an ordered pair is matched on. The error was keeping me from knowing if knew how to use the syntax.

Comment: Actually, the `function` command can do almost arbitrary pattern matching. It is just that need to prove manually that the equations are actually non-overlapping (or, if they are overlapping, they are consistent).

Comment: @Lars, so far I've stayed away from using `function` and have just used `fun`. I forgot what problems I've had exactly, but I try to add to my toolbox of doing things without `fun`. For one thing, I've found that `f` with an `if/else` with `definition`, or `f` defined with `primrec` will get proved automatically, when `f` defined with `fun` won't. With `case`, I have one more way to experiment with defining a function where I'm putting all the implementation of `f` in one formula on the right-hand side.